# Поиск текста на всей странице, .next()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты.
Сейчас занимаюсь разработкой скрипта (для личного пользования) и столкнулся с проблемой.

У меня есть таблица. К примеру, 5 столбцов и 20 рядов. Каждая первая колонка в ряде пронумерована от 1 до 20 соответственно.

Мне нужно найти тот ряд, первая колонка которого равна, к примеру, 7, а после этого взять значение из этого же ряда, но из 3-ей колонки.

Сам я сейчас учусь, но поиски в интернете сводятся к регулярным выражениям, .match, :contains и т.д. Но до конца рабочего примера не нашел нигде. Буду очень признателен, если сможете сделать такой пример для понимания. Сразу предупреждаю, скрипт накладывается на сайт, который делал не я.

По сути, мне нужно найти правильный ряд, а потом отталкиваясь от первой колонки найти значение 3-ей и дело с концом?

**UPD**
var a = $("td:contains('fgsfg')").next().next().html().val[0]

Попробовал такую штуку. Мне выдает undefined.

***UPD2***

Все эти данные должны быть доступны с других страниц. То есть, я нахожусь на главное, а оно мне считает значения из таблицы на другой какой-либо странице. Я пробовал $.get(), но не получается. Если нахожусь на странице с таблицей, всё считает. Здесь же пишет null. Что с этим делать?

***UPD3***

Помощь нужна очень срочно, никто не знает?

Comment: $.html - это функция

Comment: дада, знаю, писал уже в ночь, забыл скобки поставить :) Там всё как надо

Comment: @Vendetta8247, а как именно вы

> пробовали $.get()

?

Comment: $.get("http://url.com/1/2/tabl.php", function()
{
var text=+document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('tr')[2].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML
});

В таком случае пишет, что getElementById is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на js (для общего развития):

```
var text=document.getElementById('table_id').getElementsByTagName('tr')[row].getElementsByTagName('td')[col].innerHTML;
```

На jquery:

```
var text=$('#table_id tr:nth-child('+row+') td:nth-child('+col+')').html()
```

Comment: спасибо, но вот проблема в том, что у table нету id

Comment: @Vendetta8247, любой селектор можно использовать. Нет id - использовать класс, нет класса - отталкиваться от родительского элемента, если и с этим проблемы, а таблиц на странице несколько, то индекс поможет: или метод **.eq()**, или селектор **':eq()'**

Comment: огромное спасибо, всё наконец-то получилось :) Но теперь другая проблема. Обновил главный пост